# how to save several json locally?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm scraping a website trough it's api and I'm obtaining data in json format, given the quantity of data, i'd like to save it locally on my computer and elaborate it later.
What is the best format to store several json? I've tried making a list of json in phyton and then converting it on csv with panda, but it seems to me that several keys have disappeared on the final file.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(my_list_of_json)
df.to_csv('Path/to/a/file/on/my/computer.csv', index=False)
```

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe keeping a format closer to the original json? keeping in mind that I need to extract the data later?

Comment: Either save them as a .json file, or use pickle to save and load the object

Comment: "What is the best format to store several json?" um, as JSON probably?

Comment: You may want to debug that "several keys mssing" thing first. Its fine to save the JSON as you go, or to wite a CSV. They are both reasonable approaches. Once you have the dataframe, you could also save in one of the pandas formats like parquet.

Answer (score 0):

For analysis always keep the original data so store them as they are in `.json`.

You could of course simple create a folder and put all JSON files there but it would be better to use a Database e.g. one of the ones listed [here](https://www.quackit.com/json/tutorial/list_of_json_databases.cfm).

Answer (score 0):

```
j = '''{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}'''
  
import json

#Load json string to json object
j_obj = json.loads(j)
#Write json to file
json.dump(j_obj, open("example.json", "w"))
#load json from file
j_obj_loaded = json.load(open("example.json", "r"))
```